# Cannot import pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when I import the pandas lib in Python 2.6.6 in the server:

```
import pandas as pd
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
import pandas.core.config_init
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 18, in <module>
from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 27, in <module>
from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, _ensure_index
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2, in <module>
from pandas.indexes.api import *
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/api.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas.indexes.base import (Index, _new_Index,  # noqa
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2424
result = {k: self.take(v) for k, v in compat.iteritems(result)}
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone has an idea about this error? I checked the same file in Python 2.7 in another environment but there are no errors.

Comment: You better to update, official docs says it supports [Officially Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#python-version-support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern pandas doesn't support 2.6 any more -- see [issue #7718](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7718) and [PR #11988](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/119880).

You can (1) upgrade to a more modern version of Python (3.6 has just been released, after all), or (2) downgrade to an older version of pandas.

Upgrading is a **much** better solution, as otherwise you'll find yourself hitting bugs which have since been fixed or wanting functionality which wasn't introduced until after the last 2.6-compatible version.

Answer (score 1):

**PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions**

> This PEP was originally written for inclusion in Python 2.3.  It was
>   withdrawn after observation that substantially all of its benefits
>   were subsumed by generator expressions coupled with the dict()
>   constructor.
>
> However, Python 2.7 and 3.0 introduces this exact feature, as well as
>   the closely related set comprehensions.  On 2012-04-09, the PEP was
>   changed to reflect this reality by updating its Status to Accepted,
>   and updating the Python-Version field.  The Open Questions section was
>   also removed since these have been long resolved by the current
>   implementation.